# pandas: to_csv append mode with preserved columns order

Tags: pandas

I am using:

`df.to_csv('file.csv', header=False, mode='a')`

to write multiple pandas dataframe one by one to a CSV file.

I make sure that these dataframe have the same sets of column names.

However, it seems that the column orders will be written in a random order, so I have a chaos CSV file.

How to make sure that the new dataframe will be written with the column order of previous data?

Many thanks

Comment: Is possible create list of `DataFrame`, concat together and write big df to file?

Comment: Indeed it is possible, but the list will be very big over time.

Comment: Please check edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can sorting each `DataFrame` by columns if same columns names in each one:

```
df.sort_index(axis=1).to_csv('file.csv', header=None, mode='a')
```

If possible different columns names is possible create helper variable `c` and add new columns with removing duplicates:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'C':list('as'),
                   'B':[4,5],
                   'A':[7,8]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'D':list('as'),
                   'A':[4,5],
                   'C':[7,8]})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'C':list('as'),
                   'B':[4,5],
                   'E':[7,8]})

c = df1.columns

#first df should be written to file same way as another df
df1.to_csv('file.csv', header=None, index=False)

c = c.append(df2.columns).drop_duplicates()
df2.reindex(columns=c).to_csv('file.csv', header=None, mode='a', index=False)

c = c.append(df3.columns).drop_duplicates()
df3.reindex(columns=c).to_csv('file.csv', header=None, mode='a', index=False)

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, names=c)
print (df)
   C    B    A    D    E
0  a  4.0  7.0  NaN  NaN
1  s  5.0  8.0  NaN  NaN
2  7  NaN  4.0    a  NaN
3  8  NaN  5.0    s  NaN
4  a  4.0  NaN  NaN  7.0
5  s  5.0  NaN  NaN  8.0
```